# Show one label per shape in CartoCSS

Tags: mapbox, cartocss, mapbox-studio

I'm working in Mapbox Studio (Classic) and want to prevent labels from rendering more than once.

I'm using `text-repeat-distance` to prevent labels from showing more than once:

```
#Admin_level3_Boundary {
  line-width: 1;
  line-color: #aaa;

  [zoom>=8] {
    text-name: [AREANAME];
    text-face-name: @sans; 
    text-fill: #ccc;
    text-size: 8;
    text-avoid-edges: true;
    text-repeat-distance: 50000;
  }
}
```

According to the CartoCSS attributes outlined [here](https://github.com/mapbox/carto/blob/master/docs/latest.md), a high `text-repeat-distance` should do the trick.  But it's not working:

[image: Repeated labels]

I've tried using `text-min-distance` and `text-margin` as well, but it causes other (non-repeat) labels to disappear if they are close by.

How can I prevent repeat labels from showing?

Answer (score 1):

Polygons in Mapbox Studio Classic are often split between multiple vector tiles, which can make preventing repeated labels quite challenging, if not impossible. Many cartographers choose instead to create a separate point layer for their labels (this is how it's done in [Mapbox Streets](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/)).